# How to use inserted query id for running another query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to insert some data like this:

```
foreach($data as $arr){
    $query=DB::table('users');
    $query->insert([
          'usr_name' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
          'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
          'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);
    DB::table('members')->insert([
          'mbr_mobile' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
          'mbr_usr_id' => $query['id'], // returns error
          'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
          'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);
}
```

As you can see I tried inserting data into `users` table and then inserting data into `members` table.

But I do need the `id` of the row that data has just got inserted into `users` table, so I can use it for `mbr_usr_id`.

But this is wrong since it is showing me **Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as array** error.

And if I write `$query->id` instead of `$query['usr_id']`, I get **Undefined property** error!

So how can I use inserted query id for running another *INSERT* query in Laravel?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

And if I do this, I get **Call to a member function lastInsertId() on bool** error:

```
$lastInsertedID = $query->insert([
       'usr_name' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
       'usr_is_active' => 1,
       'usr_password' => bcrypt($arr['mbr_national_code']),
       'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
       'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
])->lastInsertId();

DB::table('members')->insert([
       ...
       'mbr_usr_id' => $lastInsertedID,
]);
```

Comment: @KenLee `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lastInsertId()`

Comment: @KenLee Would you see my **UPDATE** plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
foreach($data as $arr){
    $user_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
          'usr_name' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
          'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
          'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);
    DB::table('members')->insert([
          'mbr_mobile' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
          'mbr_usr_id' => $user_id, 
          'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
          'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this `insertGetId`
here is the example how to use it

```
$id = DB::table('users')
->insertGetId(
[
    'usr_name' => $arr['mbr_mobile'],
    'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
    'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
]);
```

Comment: Would you see my **UPDATE** plz

Comment: remove your `->lastInsertId();` and change `->insert(` to `->insertgetid`

Answer (score 0):

Use *insertGetId* instead *insert*.
Or use [Inserting & Updating via Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts), there is an id getter

Comment: Would you see my **UPDATE** plz